# How to make matrix elements variables

Tags: matrix, manipulate

I have the following matrix

```
mat := {{xx, xy}, {yx, yy}};
```

I want to be able to manipulate the matrix elements with the manipulate function

```
Manipulate[mat[xx, xy, yx, yy], {xx, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

where I want the matrix tensor to be the value that I choose

Any Ideas?

Comment: `mat` is not a function. You cannot call it as if it were a function.

Comment: To elaborate on @Szabolcs' comment, do `Clear[mat]` and then set `mat[xx_,xy_,yx_,yy_]:={{xx,xy},{yx,yy}}` instead.

Comment: Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, one way could be

[image]

```
ClearAll[xx, xy, yx, yy];
mat[xx_ : xx, xy_ : xy, yx_ : yx, yy_ : yy] := {{xx, xy}, {yx, yy}}
Manipulate[mat[xx],
 {{xx, 0, "xx"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {xx}
 ]
```

And if you want to change two entries

[image]

```
ClearAll[xx, xy, yx, yy];
mat[xx_ : xx, xy_ : xy, yx_ : yx, yy_ : yy] := {{xx, xy}, {yx, yy}}
Manipulate[mat[xx, xy],
 {{xx, 0, "xx"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{xy, 0, "xy"}, 0, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {xx, xy}
 ]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to easily input and change some matrix elements then "Manipulate" is an overkill and you may either use the palette for matrix input, found under "Palette" and "Typesetting". Or you may use keyboard input:

( ctrl enter ctrl , ctrl space )

[image]

You can then fill in the templates by clicking:

[image]

and the whole statement would look like:

[image]