# How to make a matrix a set of variables to be manipulated?

Tags: matrix, manipulate

I have the following

```
f[xx_, xy_, yx_, yy] := {{xx, xy}, {yx, yy}};
f[a_] = f[xx, xy, yx, yy]
```

but I don't want to write all the variables for future applications, I want to subsitute the matrix elements as one variable while still having the properties of the matrix elements while manipulating it

```
Manipulate[f[a], {xx, 0, 1}]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Due to the scope for control variables in the `Manipulate`, the control variable `xx` is not the same as the `xx` used in the external definitions. Look at `Manipulate[f[xx, xy, yx, yy] // MatrixForm, {{xx, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: OP posted a [related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271286) a few hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
f = Array[a, {2, 2}];
Manipulate[Evaluate[f], {a[2, 1], 0, 1}]
```

Now you have one slider that adjusts the value of a[2,1] while leaving the others alone. Or use:

```
Manipulate[Evaluate[f], {a[2, 1], 0, 1}, {a[1, 1], -1, 0}]
```

to manipulate both a[2,1] and a[1,1]. If you wish, you can retain the xx-style indexing the same way:

```
g = {{xx, xy}, {yx, yy}}; 
Manipulate[Evaluate[g], {xx, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, but how do I keep the notation with xx, xy, yx, and yy?

Comment: I thought you didn't want to have to write out all the variable names! What are you going to do for a 3 by 3 or 5 by 5? This way, you can easily select exactly those that you want to manipulate, no matter the size of the matrix.

Comment: I am not worried about the size of the matrix/tensor, I'm only working with 3x3x3 and 3x3x3x3 tensors, I was just wondering if the notation can be changed with something I am familiar with.